# Python igraph: Count distinct edges in a weighted graph

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python igraph to create a weighted graph from input files. The point is that I need the number of distinct edges (since this is a weighted graph). I know that

```
graph.ecount()
```

does not take this into account. I can do it reading the file itself and count number of distinct edges but I wanted to know if the igraph itself has a function or an attribute I can set for ecount to count distinct number of edges. Note that I use the following line of code to create my graphs:

```
graph= Graph.Read_Ncol(file, names=True, weights="if_present", directed=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: is this a multigraph? otherwise `ecount` _is_ the number of distinct edges... weighting is just an attribute of each edge.

Comment: Then how come it returns different values for weighted vs unweighted versions?

Comment: from reading online, igraph supports multigraphs from reading that function, so possibly the weights allow it to detect multiple edges, and they don't without them, not sure. if so, if you just want to know how many links exist in the graph (i.e. if two nodes have more than one edge between them, you only want that counted once), you could probably flatten `g.neighbors`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the weights matter at all here - `Graph.Read_Ncol` will simply store the weights as edge attributes and they are not taken into account by `g.ecount()`. The only thing that could matter here is that `Graph.Read_Ncol` creates a multigraph for you for some reason (in which case there could be multiple edges between the same pair of vertices). You can get rid of multiple edges (but keep the loop edges) with `g.simplify(loops=False)` and then you can call `g.ecount()`.